# How to clear variables created using eval?

Tags: matlab

I have a thousands of variables stores in .mat files. I am loading them in a loop one at a time. I then assign the loaded variable the workspace variable `x` using `eval`. Then, I clear the loaded variable. The problem is that matlab gives `The current workspace already has too many variables` error after around 60,000 iterations. But, on checking the workspace, it appears that only 5-10 variables are present.

```
for i = 1:m
    load(sprintf('feat_%s.mat', ids{i}), sprintf('feat_%s', ids{i}));
    eval(sprintf('x = feat_%s;', ids{i}));
    clear(sprintf('feat_%s', ids{i}));
end
```

I think this has got to do with the `eval` command. I am guessing that `eval` is creating multiple copies of `x`. Any idea on wow to clear variables created using `eval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best not to use `eval`. You can `load` into a variable:

```
for ii=1:m
   nm = sprintf('feat_%s', ids{ii} );
   ld = load( [nm,'.mat'], nm );
   x = ld.(nm); % access loaded variable WITHOUT eval
   clear ld; % clear the loaded variable
end
```

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` as a variable name in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab?lq=1).